# Как в QTextEdit вывести ровную ширину отформатированных строк?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

В методе **format** задается ширина строк. **print()** выводит строки строго по заданной ширине. В объекте **QTextEdit** строки выводятся не строго по ширине. Почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QApplication, QWidget
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.resize(400, 300)

txt_widget = QTextEdit()
txt_widget.resize(350, 280)

li = []
for line in range(8):
    li.append(line)
    line_two = "abcd"
    total_line = "{0:30}{1}".format(str(li), line_two)
    print(total_line)
    txt_widget.append(total_line)
vbox = QVBoxLayout()
vbox.addWidget(txt_widget)

window.setLayout(vbox)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: там куда print выводит у вас моноширинный шрифт используется.

Comment: `txt_widget.setFont(QFont("Monospace"))` - установка моноширинного шрифта. Не уверен в кроссплатформенности решения.

Comment: @mkkik правильно, спасибо. Достаточно установить моноширный шрифт. (Думал что "Monospace" - это название шрифта).